# How to solve $ \int \left(\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \right)e^{t^2-\sqrt{2}t}\ dt$

Tags: integration, analysis

$\int \left(\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \right)e^{t^2-\sqrt{2}t}\ dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $$\text{Let} \ t^2-\sqrt2 t = x \implies (2t - \sqrt2)dt=dx \implies \left(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\sqrt2}{4}\right)dt = \frac {dx}4$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int u'e^u dt =e^u$

Try taking $u=t^2-\sqrt{2}t$ and show your work if you didn't get to your answer if you want us to help you.